# How do I combine a Power BI map and a paginated report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, powerbi-paginated-reports

Currently, I have a Power BI Map that shows company locations, both by address and latitude/longitude. I am using the full address for specificity, but the lat/long for calculating distance. I'm using Great Circle formulas to calculate the distance (in miles) from a selected location to generate which stores should be visible to the user and which should not. The ones too far away (in the picture, more than 20 miles) have size = 0. The one closest to the selection has size = 1, and the ones somewhere in between have size 0.25.
[image: Power BI Locality Map]

In the data set I'm using are KPIs corresponding to all national locations. Is there a way to make a report/card/etc. that would show me the KPIs associated with the locations visible on the map? I know I can get the bubbles/labels to show a specific data point (e.g., "Customers per Week"), but there are multiple KPIs I want to show per location. It would be very handy to be able to use something like a paginated report/matrix, filtered on only the visible locations. How might I go about doing something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

You put a filter on the visual of the matrix/table/etc. with the KPIs that says
"Map Point Size > 0," so that only the visible data points show up in the table itself.